# Woocommerce move welcome message on navigation

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I want to move the welcome message that appear on my account dashboard on the navigation menu. I cut the printF function from dashboard.php to navigation.php. The issue is that it returns "Hello" without the name of the user.
Must i call some method before ?

Comment: can you include your code? and also explain what should be the expected result and what you are currently getting..

Comment: I am getting "Hello (not ? Log out)" and i would expect "Hello {username} (not ? Log out)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you define $current_user?

Like this:

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
```